# Cambiar clase a elemento en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un componente.html con este trozo de código:

```
<li class="nav-item" (click)="changeCollapsed()" aria-controls="collapseUsuarios">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <span class="w-20px text-center mr-2">
                <i class="fad fa-analytics"></i>
            </span>
            Conectividad
            <span class="w-100">
                <i [ngClass]="{'fad': true, 'float-right': true, 'fa-chevron-down': (isExpandedConectividad === false), 'fa-chevron-right' : (isExpandedConectividad === true)}"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul id="collapseConectividad" [collapse]="!isCollapsedConectividad" [isAnimated]="true" class="nav flex-column ml-5">
            <li class="nav-item">Tareas</li>
            <li class="nav-item">Diario</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Y este el código en el componente.ts:

```
export class SidebarComponent {
  isCollapsedTrabajo = false;
  isCollapsedUsuarios = false;
  isCollapsedConectividad = false;
  isExpandedConectividad = false;

  changeCollapsed(): void{
    this.isCollapsedConectividad = !this.isCollapsedConectividad;
    this.isExpandedConectividad = !this.isExpandedConectividad;
    console.log(this.isExpandedConectividad);
  }
}
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando se haga clic en el **li**, uno de los elementos **i** cambie de clase, por defecto he puesto que tenga la clase *fa-chevron-right* y quiero que al hacer clic se le quite la anterior clase mencionada y se le ponga la clase *fa-chevron-right*.

Comment: Por que no pruebas hacerlo con un ngclass?

Comment: Ya lo tengo, y no me está funcionando, esta es la parte del ngClass:

    <i [ngClass]="{'fad': true, 'float-right': true, 'fa-chevron-down': (isExpandedConectividad === false), 'fa-chevron-right' : (isExpandedConectividad === true)}"></i>

Comment: Y si pruebas con `<i [ngClass]="{'fad': true, 'float-right': true, 'fa-chevron-down': !isExpandedConectividad, 'fa-chevron-right' : isExpandedConectividad}"></i>`